# Using repeater for shopping cart

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have been cracking my head on how to solve a particular issue. I need to create a shopping cart page where user can set their quantity or remove that particular item from the cart. I have decided to use Repeater for it. And values are gotten from a database

My codes as follow

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeatStatus" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepeatStatus_ItemDataBound" onitemcommand="Button_ItemCommand" EnableViewState="False">
                   <HeaderTemplate><tr style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #3D7169">
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Total</td>
                    </tr></HeaderTemplate>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.ProductName")%></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" Height="23px" Width="50px" Text=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Quantity")%>></asp:TextBox><br />
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnRemove" Text="Remove" CommandName="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CDetailsID") %>' style="font-size:12px;"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>                                             
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Price")%>></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    <br />
                        <tr style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #6C6B66">
                        <td colspan="4" class="cartTotal">Final Price: </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="4">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmptyData" Text="No Data Found" runat="server" Visible="false" Font-Bold="True">
                                    </asp:Label></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td colspan="4">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" /> 
                        </td></tr>      
                               </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

My Code behind is this

```
 protected void RepeatStatus_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        int q;
        decimal p = 0, t = 0;
        int j = RepeatStatus.Items.Count;
        if (RepeatStatus.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem ri in RepeatStatus.Items)
            {
                if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    Label price = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPrice");
                    TextBox qty = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtQty");
                    Label total = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTotal");
                    q = Convert.ToInt32(qty.Text);
                    p = Convert.ToDecimal(price.Text.Substring(1));
                    t = (p * q);
                    total.Text = "$" + t.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        if (RepeatStatus.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
            {
                Label lblFooter = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblEmptyData");
                lblFooter.Visible = true;
                Button btnU = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnUpdate");
                btnU.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason which I have been trying so hard to find, is that the first record will always not calculate the sub pricing for the product. But the 2nd record and onward will display the value correctly. Am I doing something wrong or I should change it to using Datalist?

Comment: Have you tried using a GridView instead?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with his repeater tho.. i dont see why he should use a gridview or listview

Comment: Probably I will follow Mike suggestions first before changing it to GridView or ListView. Thanks guys! Will be back to post my results.

Answer (score 1):

`ItemDataBound` is called for each item in the list, so you'll want to limit your calculation to just that item, rather than all of the items, as you are doing now. 
Secondly, you appear to be fetching the values from the rendered data elements, rather than the data items themselves. If you can, calculate the totals on the server before binding to the `Repeater` (or `GridView` or `ListView` as others suggested).